# Get the Zip Code of the Current Location - iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

How to get the zip code of the current location using mapkit, i didn't find any API's for getting this in document. i used coordinate,attitue,horizontal,vertical,course and speed parameters of CLLocationManager, but failed to get the zip code.

Could any one please give me the API or sample code to get it done.

Is it possible to get the zip code using current location in iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the latitude and longitude to create an [MKPlacemark object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkplacemark), which includes the zip code.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick, i tested it its working, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nick Link is broken.

Answer (score 9):

Reverse Geocoding in iPhone:

First add `<MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>` framework.

```
-(void)CurrentLocationIdentifier
    {
        //---- For getting current gps location
        CLLocationManager *locationManager;
        CLLocation *currentLocation;

        locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

Reverse geocoding for getting place details using GPS location.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!(error))
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Detected\n");
             NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
             NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

             NSString *Address = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:locatedAt];
             NSString *Zipcode = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.postalCode];
             NSLog(@"%@",Zipcode);      
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error %@", error); // Error handling must required
         }
     }];
}
```

For more details to get from gps:

```
 placemark.region
 placemark.country
 placemark.locality
 placemark.name
 placemark.ocean
 placemark.postalCode
 placemark.subLocality
 placemark.location
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
func getZipCode(location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed getting zip code: \(error)")
            completion(nil)
        }
        if let postalCode = placemarks?.first?.postalCode {
            completion(postalCode)
        } else {
            print("Failed getting zip code from placemark(s): \(placemarks?.description ?? "nil")")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```